# How to add basic auth java android in AsyncTask or RequestHandler.java?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My question is how to add basic auth Java Android AsyncTask? Some of developers said it needs to be declared in `RequestHandler.java` or in `doInBackground AsyncTask` function. Below is my code:

```
private void loginTask(String _username, String _password){
        final String username = _username;
        final String password = _password;

        class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this,"Fetching...","Wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(App.URL_AUTHENTICATION);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return s;
            }
        }
        LoginTask gt = new LoginTask();
        gt.execute();
    }
```

RequestHandler class: https://github.com/IntellijSys/AndroidToDoList/blob/master/app/src/main/java/my/intellij/androidtodolist/RequestHandler.java

Comment: This code will not compile, you can't create a class inside in a method plus your username and password variable are redundant, your toast is supposedly be called on `onPostExecute` and lastly this a leaky implementation because your asynctask will hold an implicit reference to your parent class so consider using `WeakReference` or avoid a non static inner class of AsyncTask.

Comment: that one I will adjust. for basic auth, still dont have any idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            // your basic auth username and password
            rh.setBasicAuth("username","password");
String s = rh.sendGetRequest(App.URL_AUTHENTICATION);
```

RequestHandler class with Basic auth

```
import android.util.Base64;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

/**
 * Created by ZERO on 16/08/2016.
 */
public class RequestHandler {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    //Method to send httpPostRequest
    //This method is taking two arguments
    //First argument is the URL of the script to which we will send the request
    //Other is an HashMap with name value pairs containing the data to be send with the request
    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
        URL url;

        //StringBuilder object to store the message retrieved from the server
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            //Initializing Url
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            //Creating an httmlurl connection
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//set Basic auth
            processBasicAuth(conn);

            //Configuring connection properties
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //Creating an output stream
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            //Writing parameters to the request
            //We are using a method getPostDataString which is defined below
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String response;
                //Reading server response
                while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(response);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void processBasicAuth(HttpURLConnection conn) {
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            try {
                String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
                byte[] data = userPassword.getBytes("UTF-8");
                String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String sendGetRequest(String requestURL) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestURL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //set Basic auth
            processBasicAuth(con);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String s;
            while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(s + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String sendGetRequestParam(String requestURL, String id) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestURL + id);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String s;
            while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(s + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    public void setBasicAuth(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try it first

Comment: This code `rh.setBasicAuth("username","password");` just set the variable but after that it does nothing. You need to add something more in your `setBasicAuth` method.

Comment: @Enzokie look at here //set Basic auth
            processBasicAuth(conn);

Comment: yeah, but how its interact with the processBasicAuth()?

Comment: @MohammadNurdin when you call sendGetRequest();

Comment: @MohammadNurdin setBasicAuth() is a public method is a way to inject basic auth username and pass inside RequestHandler class.

Comment: nvm, I try it first

Comment: @MohammadNurdin sorry you are not getting me. if you check RequestHandler class in brief you can see how basic auth request is attached with URLConnection object. don't confused with setBasicAuth() method,you can define username and password as constants inside RequestHandler class too.

Comment: sure2. i otw testing it